# Concurrent database access pattern for web applications

Tags: java, database, spring

I'm trying to write a Spring web application on a Weblogic server that makes several independent database SELECTs(i.e. they can safely be called concurrently), one of which takes 15 minutes to execute.

Once all the results are fetched, an email containing the results will be sent to a user list.

What's a good way to get around this problem? Is there a Spring library that can help or do I go ahead and create daemon threads to do the job?

EDIT: This will have to be done at the application layer (business requirement) and the email will be sent out by the web application.

Comment: Did you mean `15 seconds` when you said, "15 minutes"?

Comment: is the problem you are worried about munging the data, or the long running request, or both?

Comment: `one of which takes 15 minutes to execute.` that is really slow, something isn't running efficiently there.

Comment: @Nishant, 15 minutes, positive. Yes, that is really long.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, more about the long running request, but both actually.

Comment: @KM, I think our DBAs know what they're doing, so I think it's because the data is simply very, very, very huge.

Comment: Look @ java.util.concurrent and related classes for concurrent execution in java.

Comment: @blob, java.util.concurrent obviously doesn't tell me how to use concurrency properly through the Spring framework though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you sure you are doing everything optimally?  15 minutes is a really long time unless you have a gabillion rows across dozens of tables and need a heckofalot of joins....this is your highest priority -- why is it taking so long?
2. Do you do the email job at set intervals, or is it invoked from your web app?  If set intervals, you should do it in an outside job, possibly on another machine.  You can use daemons or the quartz scheduler.
3. If you need to fire this process off from the web app, you need to do it asynchronously.  You could use JMS, or you could just have a table into which you enter a new job request, with daemon process that looks for new jobs every X time period.  Firing off background threads is possible, but its error prone and not worth the complication, especially since you have other valid options that are simpler.

Comment: 1. Honestly, I'm not sure everything is done optimally, but I have no control over the database. I've been given a fixed set of SQL statements to invoke, so my concern is working around this requirement and make it work at the application level.  2. The email job is invoked from my web app.  3. Adding another JMS queue subscriber will take too long a process (where I work) so I guess the only answer I have left is background threads, which is error prone as you said.  Thank you.

Comment: @russell, you should run the processing job outside of your webapp.  Why not the 'put the job request in a table and have a simple daemon ping it to process new jobs' approach?

Comment: the only thing getting in the way is I'm not authorized to create tables for that. Or were you speaking more figuratively? I'm sure what the experts here recommended are the best ways to go, but in my case, I might need a workaround.

Comment: @russell, yeah thats in the way.  You might want to suggest it to the people in charge.  Sell it by pointing out the advantages of the approach and the disadvantages of other approaches.  You are just trying to minimize risk and maximize maintainability....

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about Spring support for long-running, possibly asynchronous tasks, you have a choice between Spring JMS [support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) and Spring [Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

Comment: I might want to look at Batch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring quartz to schedule the job.  That way the jobs will run in the same container but will not require an http request to trigger them.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking into this too.